# How to loop two arrays and if values are equal echo something of not echo something else

Tags: php, loops

I have two arrays. The first is an array with 290 dates. The second is array with 3 dates.
I tried so many things and non of them worked.
This is my code.

```
foreach ($this->routes as $index=>$route) {
 if ($route['dateendRoute'] == $date) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $route['dateendRoute'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $route['total_distance'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $route['total_distance'] . '</td>';
    echo '<tr>';
    unset($this->routes[$index]);
 } else {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
    echo '<td colspan=3>no data</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
 }
}
```

This is what i am receiving.

```
2014-01-09  2014-01-09  12.01   12.01
2014-01-09  no data
2014-01-09  no data
2014-01-10  no data
2014-01-10  2014-01-10  13.37   13.37
2014-01-10  no data
2014-01-11  no data
2014-01-11  no data
2014-01-11  no data
2014-01-12  no data
2014-01-12  no data
2014-01-12  no data
2014-01-13  no data
2014-01-13  no data
2014-01-13  no data
2014-01-14  no data
2014-01-14  no data
2014-01-14  2014-01-14  12.88   12.88
2014-01-15  no data
2014-01-15  no data
2014-01-15  no data
```

What I want to receive is this.

```
2014-01-09  2014-01-09  12.01   12.01
2014-01-10  2014-01-10  13.37   13.37
2014-01-11  no data
2014-01-12  no data
2014-01-13  no data
2014-01-14  2014-01-14  12.88   12.88
2014-01-15  no data
```

Please help :)

Comment: You'll need to sort the arrays by date to due a chronological comparison.

Comment: May we see the rest of the code, the code that loops dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mocking out the arrays

```
$dates = array('2014-01-09','2014-01-10','2014-01-11','2014-01-12','2014-01-13','2014-01-14','2014-01-15');
$routes = array(
  array('dateendRoute' => '2014-01-09', 'total_distance' => '1.1'),
  array('dateendRoute' => '2014-01-11', 'total_distance' => '2.2'),
  array('dateendRoute' => '2014-01-14', 'total_distance' => '3.3')
);
```

loop through each date

```
foreach($dates as $date) {
  //assume no matches found
  $no_match = TRUE;
  foreach ($routes as $index=>$route) {
    if ($route['dateendRoute'] == $date) {
      //match found so switch this variable
      $no_match = FALSE;
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $route['dateendRoute'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $route['total_distance'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td>' . $route['total_distance'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
  //check if match found after looping through routes array
  if($no_match) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
    echo '<td colspan=3>no data</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
```

this will produce the following output

```
2014-01-09  2014-01-09  1.1 1.1
2014-01-10  no data
2014-01-11  2014-01-11  2.2 2.2
2014-01-12  no data
2014-01-13  no data
2014-01-14  2014-01-14  3.3 3.3
2014-01-15  no data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to make your array with date key 
foreach ($this->routes as $index=>$route) {
 if ($route['dateendRoute'] == $date) {
     $array[$date]=$your_value_is_here;
 } else {
     $array[$date]=$date." There is no data available ";
 }
}

and then print your array respective with your view
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a smaller data set as follows:

```
$dates = array(
    '2014-01-09',
    '2014-01-10',
    '2014-01-11',
);

$routes = array(
    array(
        'dateendRoute'=>'2014-01-10',
        'total_distance'=>'2',
    ),
);
```

And then I updated your function as follows:

```
foreach ($this->dates as $date) {
    $routeIndex = -1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->routes); $i++) {
        if ($this->routes[$i]['dateendRoute'] == $date) {
            $routeIndex = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
    if ($routeIndex != -1) {
        echo '<td>' . $this->routes[$routeIndex]['dateendRoute'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $this->routes[$routeIndex]['total_distance'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $this->routes[$routeIndex]['total_distance'] . '</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td colspan=3>no data</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

This produces what I believe you're looking for:

```
2014-01-09  no data
2014-01-10  2014-01-10  2   2
2014-01-11  no data
```